# Google Vision API: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, rest, google-vision

I have problem with my properties from my json response body.

The reponse I get from the call is from Google Vision API.
The property 'description' is undefined but will show up when logged in the console sometimes this will works.

```
 this.http.post(this.apiUri, this.bodyAPI).subscribe((response : any) => 

{
  //console.log(response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[1].description);
  //console.log(this.photoTasks[this.activeTask].task_solution);
    if (response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[0].description? == "magenta"){
      console.log("great, " + response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[0].topicality * 100 + "% accuracy");
    }
    else if (response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[1].description == "magenta"){
      console.log("great, " + response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[1].topicality * 100 + "% accuracy");
    }
    else if (response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[2].description == this.photoTasks[this.activeTask].task_solution){
      console.log("great, " + response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[2].topicality * 100 + "% accuracy");
    }
    else if (response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[3].description == this.photoTasks[this.activeTask].task_solution){
      console.log("great, " + response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[3].topicality * 100 + "% accuracy");
    }
    // else if (response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[4].description == this.photoTasks[this.activeTask].task_solution){
    //   console.log("great, " + response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[4].topicality * 100 + "% accuracy");
    // }
    else{
      console.log("you should try again...");
    }

}  
  //console.log(response.responses[0].labelAnnotations);
) ;
}
```

This is the error:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber._next (cameraintent.component.ts:94)
```

Comment: why you have added `?` , `...nnotations[0].description?` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your response is not null?

It can also happen that response contains data, but not the labelAnnotations array, or it contains a smaller array than what you are looking for (index 4 might not exist, for example).
Try the adding the optional ? on different items that can be null, like:

```
response?.responses[0].labelAnnotations[0].description
response.responses[0]?.labelAnnotations[0].description
response.responses[0].labelAnnotations[0]?.description
```

In order to get a better understanding of what is coming up short and isn't always present. After you find out what is not always present, you can prepare your code to deal with those cases. Like adding an if condition to only log to console in case that particular field is not null.